# "Assign an Azure AD identity to your server and add Directory Reader permission to your identity" - Error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, yaml, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am writing a little thing in YAML to assign permissions to a newly built SQL Server.

```
az account set --subscription $(SubscriptionId)
        Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force
        $sqlCmd = "CREATE LOGIN [Users-PreProd2] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"
        Write-Host $env:tenantId
        $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST  -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$env:tenantId/oauth2/token" -Body @{ resource="https://database.windows.net/"; grant_type="client_credentials"; client_id=$env:servicePrincipalId; client_secret=$env:servicePrincipalKey } -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        $access_token = $request.access_token
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance database.windows.net -AccessToken $access_token -query $sqlCmd
```

I have a group called User-PreProd which i need adding as a 'CREATE LOGIN' in SQL. I have added the Service Prinicipal in the Azure AD Admin group. I can get the token fine and when i assign the token to the invoke-Sqlcmd i get an error saying :

> Error message: 'Server identity is not configured. Please follow the
> steps in "Assign an Azure AD identity to your server and add Directory
> Reader permission to your identity"

I guess the service principal i running this on needs the directory readers role. I am not sure as i have not seen this error before. I need to be correct before passing the request  on to my team members.

Comment: Is this SQL Server on an Azure VM, or an Azure SQL Database Managed Instance?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , its on Azure VM

Comment: Now I'm confused.  SQL Server on a VM doesn't support AAD auth (yet), and ServerInstance says "database.windows.net".

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - i have removed the server name...  I have used a token instead and I can make simple SQL commands work like create user 'jason' passwird 'hello' and it works fine.

Comment: So it's not SQL Server on an Azure VM.  Is it Managed Instance?

Comment: In fact actually yes !! Sorry David

Answer (score 0):

Before you can add AAD identities, the managed instance identity must have the "Directory Readers" role in AAD.

> For SQL Managed Instance, the Directory Readers role must be assigned
> to managed instance identity before you can set up an Azure AD admin
> for the managed instance.

[Directory Readers role in Azure Active Directory for Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-directory-readers-role)